# How do C Integer Literals work?

Tags: c, integer, literals

For example, how are the following statements equal to each other?

a) 0116 = 0x4E

b) 97 = 00141 = 0x0061

c) 45 = 0x2d= 0055

Ive tried looking it up but it still doesn't make sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: Numbers starting with a `0` are octal numbers.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: Translate each number to binary.

Comment: What do you mean "How do C Integer Literals work"? Are you trying to understand number systems, or how a C compiler interrupts various integer literals it encounters in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it begins with `0x` or `0X`, it is a hexadecimal number, ie. base `16`.

Else if it begins with just `0`, it is an octal number, ie. base `8`.

Else it is a decimal number, ie. base 10.

(the following is non-standard - a gcc extension)

if it begins with `0b`, it is a binary number, ie. base `2`.

Comment: C and C++ doesn't have binary integer literals (yet).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg gcc does support `0b` http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html 
not sure if c standard concurs though

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand that if it started with 0 it was base 8. I just assumed it was still base 10.

Comment: It's an extension, it's not in the C standard yet. It's planned for C++14 though, might be in the next C standard as well.

Answer (score 0):

number starting with 0 is octal number
number starting with 0x is hexadecimal

we need to differentiate between two different number system and in programming we do it this way

if you want to verify these equalities you can solve it by yourself or you can use online converter. i am giving you link below

http://calc.50x.eu/

Comment: And yes, that means that `0` is an octal literal, not decimal. (Which doesn't matter; it has the same value it would have if it were decimal.)

Comment: yes on converting it from octal to decimal we get right value

Answer (score 0):

Numbers starting with a `0` are in octal. Octal digits between 0 and 7. Counting in octal goes:
`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, ...`

Numbers starting with a `0x` or `0X` are in hexadecimal (hex). Hex uses digits and alpha values. Counting in Hex goes:
`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, 10, ...`

So how is 0116<sub>8</sub> == 0x4E<sub>16</sub>?

The C compiler will see the `0` in `0116` and know to interrupt the number as octal. The compiler can check different number systems against each other where as we, mostly humans, need to convert them to something we can understand better.

Converting Octal to Decimal can be done as the Σ (for i=0 to n) of the function: a<sub>i</sub>x8<sup>i</sup>. In your example:

1x8<sup>2</sup> = 64

1x8<sup>1</sup> = 8

6x8<sup>0</sup> = 6

64+8+6 = 78<sub>10</sub>

Converting Hex to Decimal can be done with nearly the same formula but you need to convert each letter to the decimal equivalent for the a<sub>i</sub> portion of: a<sub>i</sub>x16<sup>i</sup>. 

4x16<sup>1</sup> = 64

14x16<sup>0</sup> = 14     //E<sub>16</sub> == 14<sub>10</sub>

64+14 = 78<sub>10</sub>

Clearly 78==78, the compilter just doesn't need to do the conversion first to see that.